# Show strong operator convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, strong-convergence

I have a problem in which I need to prove that a sequence of operators is strongly convergent and that it isn't uniformly convergent. The operators are defined like so:  $ T_j: L^1 \to L^∞ $

And the sequence goes on as such:

$$
T_1(x) = (x_1, x_1, x_1, x_1,...)
$$
$$
T_2(x) = (x_1, x_2, x_2, x_2,...)
$$
$$
T_3(x) = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_3,...)
$$
$$
T_n(x) = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n, x_n,...)
$$

For the first part of the problem I couldn't really come up with anything because I'm new to functional analysis but for the second part in which I tried to prove that the sequence isn't uniformly convergent, I tried this:

$$
||T_nx|| = ||(x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n, x_n,...)||\\ = ||(x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., 0, 0,...) + (0, 0, 0, ..., x_n, x_n,...)||
$$
$$
||T_nx|| \le \sup\limits_{i}||x_i|| + |x_n| = c\\ ||T_n|| = \sup \frac{||T_nx||}{||x||} = \sup\limits_{||x|| = 1}||T_nx|| = c
$$

Since we cannot say that $c$ ($\ge0$) equals to zero, $||T_n - 0|| = ||T_n||$ does not converge uniformly to zero.

First of all I would really like to know if my solution to the second part is true or not. Also, if you can give me any ideas as to how I can show strong convergence or provide solutions, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

Edit 1: As @postmortes suggested, to show strong operator convergence, looking at $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}||T_nx - x||$ we can see that $T_nx$ converges to zero since $$T_nx - x = (0,0,0,...,0,x_n - x_{n+1}, x_n - x_{n+2},...)$$ and as $n\to∞$ this is going to be zero so $T_nx\to x$ (Strong convergence means that $||T_nx - Tx|| \to 0$ and here that $T$ operator is the identity operator $I$ where $Ix = x$)

Edit 2: As @JustDroppedIn stated, my way of showing that the sequence does not converge uniformly is wrong.

Comment: @postmortes I initially used the approach I mentioned to show strong convergence and I did try what you said but I can't seem to figure out how $T_nx$ converges to anything.

Comment: @postmortes Yes but I thought that strong convergence, in concrete terms, meant $||T_nx - Tx|| \to 0$

Comment: I see, thank you I really appreciate your patience

Comment: @postmortes I added an answer with basically what is being discussed in the comments and a small explanation to why the convergence occurs:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $x=(x_n)\in\ell^1$, then $x\in\ell^\infty$ as well. Now

$$\|T_nx-x\|_{\ell^\infty}=\|(0,0,,\dots,0,x_n-x_{n+1},x_n-x_{n+2},x_n-x_{n+3},\dots)\|_\infty=\sup_{k\geq1}|x_n-x_{n+k}|$$
But since $x\in\ell^1$ we have that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence (since it converges (to $0$)). So if $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\geq1$ so that $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$. Then, for $n\geq N$ we have that
$$\|T_nx-x\|_\infty=\sup_{k\geq1}|x_n-x_{n+k}|\leq\varepsilon$$
which shows that $T_nx\to x$ in $\ell^\infty$. In other words, since this is true for all $x$, we have that $T_n\to I$ strongly, where $I:\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$ is the identity operator.

comment: Note that the same would be true if we "enlarged" the domain of each $T_n$ and used the space $c$ of convergent sequences with supremum norm.

### Edit

Here are some details about checking whether $T_n$ converges in norm, as OP seems to have trouble with this part.

First, if $T_n$ converges in norm to something, it has to be $I$, because if $T_n$ converges in norm to $S$, then $T_n$ converges strongly to $S$ and therefore $S=I$ (strong operator limits are unique).

First let's compute the norm of $T_n$, but this is **not needed** to check whether $T_n\to I$ in norm; we should be computing $\|T_n-I\|$ for this, but let's start with that. Note that $n$ is fixed now! We have that $$\|T_n\|=\sup_{\|x\|_{\ell^1}=1}\|T_nx\|_{\ell^\infty}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_n,x_n,\dots)\|_{\ell^\infty}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg\{\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|x_j|\bigg\}\leq\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|\bigg\}=1 $$
So $\|T_n\|\leq1$. On the other hand, if $x=(1,0,0,\dots)$ then $\|x\|_{\ell^1}=1$ and $T_nx=(1,0,0,\dots,)$ and $\|T_nx\|_{\ell^\infty}=1$, so
$$\|T_n\|=\sup_{\|y\|_{\ell^1}}\|T_n(y)\|\geq\|T_n(x)\|=1$$
and this shows that $\|T_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

Now let's compute in the same fashion the norm of $T_n-I$, again $n$ is fixed. We do not really need to do an exact calculation, we only need to know if $\|T_n-I\|$ converges to $0$ or not. By our earlier computations before the edit,
$$\|T_n-I\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T_nx-x\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sup_{k\geq1}|x_n-x_{n+k}|$$
Now consider $x=(0,\dots,0,0,1,0,\dots)$ where $1$ appears in the $n+1$ position. Then, $\sup_{k\geq1}|x_n-x_{n+k}|=sup_{k\geq1}|x_{n+k}|=|x_{n+1}|=1$. Also note that $\|x\|_{\ell^1}=1$, so,
$$\|T_n-I\|\geq\|T_nx-x\|_{\ell^\infty}=1$$
This shows that the sequence $\{\|T_n-I\|\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is ALWAYS greater than or equal to $1$, so it cannot converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I was wondering if you could also tell me whether if I was successful at showing that the sequence isn't uniformly convergent or not?

Comment: @rev Sure. I'm afraid what you present is not correct. You say that $\|T_n\|=c$ and that since we cannot say $c=0$ this does not show uniform convergence. First, if $c=0$ then $T_n=0$! so what's the point? maybe you wanted to say that $\|T_n\|=c_n$ and that "since we cannot say $c_n\to0$ this does not show uniform convergence"? Again, it would be wrong though for two reasons: a) if we cannot say this, then there is still a chance that it is true but we failed to prove it, so we simply don't know based on that reason. and b) even if $T_n$ was convergent uniformly, it would converge uniformy,

Comment: @rev it would converge uniformly to its strong limit, i.e. to the operator $I$. So you would have to check whether $\|T_n-I\|$ converges to $0$ or not. If it converges to $0$, then $T_n\to I$ "uniformly", i.e. in norm. If not, then it doesn't.

Comment: I see, thank you again for the detailed explanation

Comment: @rev If you have trouble checking whether $\|T_n-I\|\to0$ or not, let me know and I will add the details to my answer, but I recommend trying it out, it will be a good exercise after this conversation:)

Comment: I will try it out and let you know as soon as I can :)

Comment: I guess I kind of failed. I tried going about it like this: $||T_n|| = \sup\frac{||T_nx||}{||x||} = \sup\limits_{||x|| = 1}||T_nx||$ since you stated earlier that $T_n \to x$, this would be equal to $\sup\limits_{||x|| = 1} ||x|| = 1$ and so $||T_n|| = 1$. But doesn't that mean $||T_n - I|| \to 0$ ?

Comment: @rev It's okay. It is important to distinguish what is fixed and what is not and keep your notation clear ($T_n\to x$ does not really make sense). I will add details in my answer

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to write $T_nx \to x$ like you stated

Comment: @rev I added some details, I hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is just really useful, honestly thank you so much! Just one question to make it all clear to myself: why didn't you say $||T_n - I|| = ||T_nx - x||_{ℓ^∞} = 1$ instead of $||T_n - I|| \ge ||T_nx - x||_{ℓ^∞} = 1$?

Comment: @rev  the norm of this operator is equal to the supremum of all such x. This might be greater than this quantity of this particular x. Glad i could help.

Comment: Another question just popped in my head after I looked at the edit more closely. What if we had chosen $x = (1,...,0,0,0,0,...)$? Wouldn't the norm $\sup\limits_{k \ge 1}|x_n - x_{n + k}|$ be equal to zero? If so then I don't think we could've said that $||T_n - I|| \ge 1$ (always)

Comment: I mean what if $1$ appeared anywhere before the $n+1$ position? Would $||T_n - I|| \ge 1$ still hold?

Comment: @rev i think you should review the basics. Do you know what a supremum is?

Comment: It's the least upper bound of a set. But for the  $x$ I mentioned wouldn't the supremum of the set $|{x_n - x_{n+k}}|$ for $k \ge 1$ be zero since they are all just zeroes. I know supremum isn't necessarily included in the set itself but how can we say that it is $1$?

Comment: @rev the supremul is taken over all x. This is one particular x.

Comment: As I was writing it I answered my own question. Yes you are absolutely right, thank you for your patience.